# Creating a matrix with System.Buffers (ArrayPool) in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to create a matrix using System.Buffers or ArrayPool in C# is this possible?

All of the examples appear to be single dimension arrays, or for jagged array of fixed size.

I don't want to create a mulit-dimension array (jagged array) I want to create a matrix because it's going to be used to pass some data via interop.

eg:

```
var matrix = new object[9000,9000];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Matrix'? A [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) (i.e. `[,]`) is *not* jagged (i.e. `[][]`). But in many cases you would use wrapper around a single dimensional array to describe a matrix. This is especially true for interop scenarios since few languages supports multidimensional arrays. Multidimensional arrays *is* such a wrapper, but does not allow direct access to the storage, so are rather limited in interop scenarios.

Comment: A 9000 by 9000 matrix is conceptually the same thing as an 81 million element single-dimension array with a note that they should be accessed as two dimensions, and can typically be allocated and passed as such (and then accessed by methods like `Span.Slice`). This makes for less convenient access in managed code when done this way, of course. If it's only for interop, you can go the other way with `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref matrix[0, 0], matrix.Length)`, or use any other approach to take the address of the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no, you need to linearize"; `ArrayPool<T>` only deals with vectors, i.e. single-dimension arrays with zero base-offset; this is partly because they're the most common scenario, and partly because of cache hits - i.e. if you only need to worry about a single size dimension, it is easy to pool arrays with a good chance of them reused, but if you need to worry about two (or more) dimensions, the semantics for reuse become a lot more complex, and the number of "hits" (i.e. reused buffers) drops significantly (in the general case).

Fundamentally, though, the actual *payload* space of an array is identical in all cases - it is just a chunk of memory the size of the multiple of all the dimensions - so a `T[n,m]` is the same *payload size* as a `T[n*m]`. When talking about interop, you're ultimately just passing the root address of that memory *anyway*, and the consumer will need to de-linearize, so: perhaps just use a vector in the first place, and de-linearize yourself using whatever dimension order needed by the interop layer.